# In R, why is my Excel Table being organized properly

Tags: r, excel

I am read the csv file, UMP into R and when I enter the print command, the data goes from a basic table that is not even anymore, and this is causing my plotted graph to become a complete mess.
[image]

How can I make sure my Excel CSV file is read properly?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table doesn't have an header.
Try:

```
data <- read.csv('mytable.csv',header=F)

colnames(data) <- c('year','value')
```

Comment: Also I wanted to ask when I entered the code I got a second curve on the graph still, the curve listed V1 keeps showing up. How may I delete the line? The V1 line is still passing through it. I see the V1 column in the table I printed and it goes from 1 to 11. (since i have 11 entries in the other two columns)

Comment: could you provide result of `dput(data)` you get?

Comment: Sure: https://ibb.co/fdmPF8P
https://ibb.co/jJwRpLG       The two links here show what the table looks like now, it still seems to have that V1 variable but not sure how to get rid of it so it doesn't get plotted

Comment: try `plot(rownames(data), data$V2)`

Comment: dat1 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\brian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\UMP.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat1 = ts(dat1, start=c(2010), end=c(2020))
colnames(dat1) <- c('Year','value')
print(dat1)
summary(dat1)
start(dat1)
end(dat1)
ts.plot(dat1, xlab="Year", ylab="Percent unemployed", main="Monthly Unemployment rate in Florida, 2010-2020")         I named the data dat1 but I provided the codes I entered up until that point. I'll check and see if the row/names works hopefully.